# JMeter not showing Sampler JAR

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Moderators, please read through once before marking it as a duplicate.

This is my first time creating a custom Sampler in JMeter. I am trying a simple query.

```
public class CustomJavaSampler extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5838315675279087366L;

    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0) {

        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        result.sampleStart(); // start stopwatch

         JMeterVariables vars = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
        vars.putObject("search", "DoASearch");
        JMeterContextService.getContext().setVariables(vars);

        result.sampleEnd(); // stop stopwatch
        result.setSuccessful(true);
        result.setResponseMessage("Successfull");
        result.setResponseCodeOK(); // 200 code

        return result;
    }

}
```

I have created a jar and I've added it to the lib/ext folder in jmeter. But I am not able to see the class in Java Request sampler.
I have enabled debug logs.

```
log_level.jmeter=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.junit=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.control=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.testbeans=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.engine=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.threads=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.gui=WARN
log_level.jmeter.testelement=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.util=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.util.classfinder=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.test=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http=DEBUG
# For CookieManager, AuthManager etc:
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http.control=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.protocol.ftp=WARN
log_level.jmeter.protocol.jdbc=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.protocol.java=WARN
log_level.jmeter.testelements.property=DEBUG
log_level.jorphan=DEBUG

log_file=jmeter-debug.log
```

The complete jmeter log is http://pastebin.com/T39iUhFW

And also why is the log showing a "did not find" message for the /lib jars?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code, CustomJavaSampler is displayed in Java Request classnames.

[image: Java Custom Sampler]

So perhaps it's something with your .jar file. Can you upload it somewhere so we could take a look? I guess it's `samp.jar`.

By the way, setting a variable is a very "light" operation which can be done via [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) which is almost Java compatible.

If you need to perform some load - next option is [JSR223 Sampler and "groovy"](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) which is a "balance" between simplicity and productivity so if you will need to make some changes in your code you won't have to recompile, replace jars, restart JMeter, etc.

Comment: Thanks.. I do know about beanshell and the JSR sampler. I wanted to write a sampler on my own, so I tried this as a HelloWorld.